# A Lemma in Transfinite Recursion Theorem

Tags: proof-verification, order-theory, ordinals

> **Transfinite Recursion Theorem:**
>
> Let $G:V\to V$ be a class function. Then there is a unique function $F:\operatorname{Ord}\to V$ such that $$\forall \alpha\in \operatorname{Ord}:F(\alpha)=G(F\restriction\alpha)$$

---

I'm struggling with proving Transfinite Recursion Theorem by myself, so I break the theorem into smaller parts to handle with more ease. Does this proof look fine or contain problems? I'm very grateful for your verification!

---

> **Lemma:** For all $\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}$, let $f_{\alpha}$ be a function such that $$\operatorname{dom}f_{\alpha}=\alpha\text{ and }\forall \gamma<\alpha:f_{\alpha}(\gamma)=G(f_{\alpha}\restriction\gamma)$$ Then $$\forall\alpha,\beta\in\operatorname{Ord}:\alpha<\beta\implies f_{\beta}\restriction \alpha =f_{\alpha}$$

---

**My attempt:**

The proof is by Transfinite Induction.

Let $P=\{\alpha\in\operatorname{Ord}\mid \alpha<\beta\implies f_{\beta}\restriction \alpha =f_{\alpha}\}$.

Assume that $\forall\alpha<\gamma:\alpha\in P$. This means $\forall\alpha<\gamma:\alpha<\beta\implies f_{\beta}\restriction \alpha =f_{\alpha}$.

By Inductive Hypothesis, $\delta<\gamma<\beta \implies f_{\beta}\restriction \delta=f_{\delta}$ and $f_{\gamma}\restriction \delta=f_{\delta}\implies f_{\beta}\restriction \delta=f_{\gamma}\restriction \delta$ $\implies G(f_{\beta}\restriction \delta) = G(f_{\gamma} \restriction \delta)\implies f_{\beta}(\delta)=f_{\gamma}(\delta)$.  It follows that $f_{\beta}\restriction\gamma=f_{\gamma}$. Hence $\gamma\in P$.

This completes the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little problem with $\beta$, you never defined it.

I think you meant to say in $P$ that $\forall \beta(\alpha<\beta\implies...)$ and then at $\delta<\gamma<\beta$ it is for arbitrary $\beta$.

If this is what you meant you proof is correct.

Here is a different way, which avoid the use of proper class(apart from $V$).

---

Let $f:\alpha\to V,g:\gamma\to V, f(x)=G(f\restriction x), g(y)=G(g\restriction y)$

Assume $\gamma\in\alpha(\gamma<\alpha)$.

Let $\delta<\gamma$ satisfy the induction requirements, for all ordinals lesser than $\delta$ we have $f,g$ equal.

From assumption we have $f\restriction \delta=g\restriction \delta$

Thus $G(f\restriction \delta)=G(g\restriction \delta)$

But this is nothing more than $f(\delta)=g(\delta)$.

This means that $\forall\delta\in\gamma(\delta<\gamma)(f(\delta)=g(\delta))$ hence $f\restriction \gamma=g$.

This is exactly the same as yours apart from the fact that my $f,g$ are fixed so it is easier to follow in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you Holo! I've not logged in my account for a week, so I don't know you have posted an answer here! Thank you so much!

Comment: Yep, I meant what you have mentioned :)

Comment: I'm very sorry for this late reply!